# Crear botón limpiar en TypeScript y este deseleccione los valores de radio button

Tags: html, typescript, botón, radiobutton

**HTML INPUT RADIO vaciar el valor de un radioButton con TypeScript**

Tengo error al limpiar el radioButton del HTML

código HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]